# Jasper report images only shown in Java execution

Tags: java, jasper-reports

In JasperReports, we have a report that shows some pictures. The problem is that this works correctly when executing from Java (in the studio or on the server). However, when exporting as a PDF or DOCX the image won't show.

The XML of the JRXML is shown bellow.

```
        <image scaleImage="FillFrame" hAlign="Center" isUsingCache="false" isLazy="true" onErrorType="Blank">
            <reportElement x="115" y="400" width="330" height="210" uuid="1363ebd2-bd5f-482b-99c3-d5cc11480dc3"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["https://someurl/documents/"+$F{locationImagePath}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
```

Comment: Did you check the url in generated *DOCX* or *PDF* file?

Comment: Checked but could not find the url (except for the url that i output as text). Don't know what a image element would be in the docx xml though, tried to find something like image, picture etc. but those are not in the file.